# Select2 JS value searching

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

[image]

Hello, i'am using select2 js, for my project but the value of select2 js show searching...

this is my code

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Seat</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control select2" multiple="" id="seat" name="seat[]" required>
                <?php if($seat != ""){ ?>
                <?php foreach ($seat as $mm) : ?>
                    <option value="<?= $mm->id ?>" data-select2-id="<?=$mm->id?>"><?= $mm->seat ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php } else {?>
                    <option value="">Please create seat in menu master data -> seat</option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
         <div id="alert-seat" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and im using Select2 4.0.13
its not always show value searching...
but sometimes its value [image]searching... like image above

Comment: Are you using AJAX to find the results? Can you please add the JS code you use to initialise the Select2 instance in to the question.

Comment: oh im sorry, i think i get the answer.. 
all i need is to re declare again the select2 js when open the modal..

and then its working..

anyway sorry for bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the answer..
just re-declare the select2 js and then its working..